# Azure Devops - How to reset Resource Group in Edit service connection

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In renewing the secret key for a service connection, I accidentally also set `Resource group` to a specific group, whereas previously it was left blank so it had access to the whole subscription.

I want to revert it back so it has access to the whole subscription, but I cannot seem to clear out the `Resource group`, it seems like once it's set, it cannot be cleared out.

Short of deleting this service connection and creating a new one with same name, is there some other way to set `Resource Group` to blank/empty spaces?  I could not find any `az cli` or `ps` command. I know I could manually grant access to the service principals but then it could be misleading from the UI perspective since it only shows one `resource group`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is purely a UI limitation. If you open your Chrome Developer Tools, you can see the request being sent in the Network tab, with the "scope" property and its value.
If the same request is sent, where scope is empty (as @unknown has shown in his answer), you'll get your desired result.

You can do this easily by right clicking the request in the network tab of your Chrome Developer Tools (after clicking "Save"), and choose Copy As -> Copy As Fetch.

Then paste this into your console of Chrome, update the body so that the scope is just an empty string, and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

We can't change the resource group to empty in the UI since it is by design.

There is a workaround to use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update-service-endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to modify the service connection. Please see the similar case:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-change-resource-group-to-empty-in-/1396077.

Get Request Body:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{endpointId}?api-version=7.1-preview.4
```

Update Service connection:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{endpointId}?api-version=7.1-preview.4
```

Please set the scope as empty.

```
"authorization": {
    "parameters": {
        "tenantid": "",
        "serviceprincipalid": "",
        "authenticationType": "spnKey",
        "scope": "",  // this is the resource group
        "serviceprincipalkey": null
    },
    "scheme": "ServicePrincipal"
},
```

Comment: This seems to have broken the service connection from the UI point of view.  After clearing the "scope" and updating it, the service connection "disappeared" from an API point of view, but it still exists in the UI, but any attempt to save the connection in the UI results in error "Service connection field not specified Parameter name: azureSpnRoleAssignmentId".  I'm going to try to delete the endpoints and create new ones.